# C# DataGridView Image Preview with loop

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview

I want to display each datagrid view row id matched jpg files to the grid view,
The problem is showing the last row id matched image for all rows. how to fix below code?

I have modified the code below:

```
        string cerNumber = "";
        DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"Output\10032-2.jpg");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            cerNumber = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["No"].Value.ToString();
            image = Image.FromFile(@"Output\" + cerNumber + ".jpg");
            
        }
        img.Image = resizeImage((image), new Size(40, 20));
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
        img.HeaderText = "Image";
        img.Name = "img";
```

Comment: So you add a new column to the dgv for each row?

Comment: Yes, I have added a new column to display id jpg from column one id name? The problem is it showing only the last id image, not each id particular image. How to fix this?

Comment: No I mean you add a new column for each row - you do this 100 times `dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);` so you add 100 image columns?

Comment: Perhaps the extra columns aren't displayed and only the first is, so you see the first image in all the rows

Comment: DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                string cerNumber = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["No"].Value.ToString();                               
                Image image = Image.FromFile(@"Output\" + cerNumber + ".jpg");
                img.Image = resizeImage((image), new Size(40, 20));
                
            }
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
            img.HeaderText = "Image";
            img.Name = "img";

Comment: I have modified the code, but now I'm receiving null error

Comment: I have mentioned the modified code above, kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the column once, then set the column value property to each image loaded in the loop

```cs
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn() { Name = "img", HeaderText = "Image" });
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = resizeImage(Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine("Output", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["No"].Value.ToString() + ".jpg")), new Size(40, 20));
```

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = resizeImage(Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine("Output", $"{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["No"].Value}.jpg")), new Size(40, 20));

Above resizeImage it's generating an error, I have mentioned below resizeImage error, Can you please let me know what is the error?


  public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
        }

Comment: Maybe it's in the resizeImage method. Check this method: http://csharpexamples.com/c-resize-bitmap-example/

Comment: I have change to above resize code, now there is an error $"{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["No"].Value}.jpg" here, please advise

Comment: You probably can't do string interpolation because of an older version of Visual Studio. Check my updated answer

Comment: Great! Thank you for the answer and quick support